# Is this following define a metrics?

Tags: metric-spaces

Is  this following define a metrics

$d((x, y), (x’, y’)) = \min\{|x – x’|, |y – y’|\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

As i found the answer  [Which of the following define a metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273333/which-of-the-following-define-a-metric//)  but not getting in my head

my attempts :i found all the metric properties   are satisfies  ...im not getting which metric proerpties is no satisfies here ......pliz help me 
i would be grateful  ----any hints or solution will be appreciated

thanks in advances

Comment: "When is that thing $0$?"

Comment: @G.Sassatelli but that non negativity property  hold...if i put x=y=o=x'=y'

Comment: There are three "*that*" here: the one I have in mind, the one you think you have in mind, and the one you've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $x=(5,0)$ and $y=(1,0)$. Then $d(x,y)=0$ but $x \neq y$

Comment: Thanks a lot @linkingpark

Answer (score 1):

A metric needs $d(z,z') = 0$ if and only if $z = z'$. Can you find an example of $(x,y) \neq (x',y')$ such that the distance is $0$?

Comment: thanks a lots Y. Forman